# Create a method like current_user for devise's current resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I want to create a method like current_user for devise's current resources.
Suppose I have two resources like User and Admin and devise is associated with both. So as usual it dynamically creates it's default methods like current_user and current_admin.

It creates it by defining like this in file [lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb):

```
def current_#{mapping}
```

How can I add a new method like this to it's dynamic methods.

I want to implement it with devise methods, so that when devise initializes then my method is also initialize with same mapping name.

Comment: User and Admin different model and table?

Comment: Yes they are different tables

Comment: if your `Devise` model is called `Member` instead of `User`, for example, then the helpers available are: `current_member` or `member_session`.

Comment: Yes I know that but I just wanted to add my own method with devise methods which will generate methods like user_policies, present_policies.

Answer (score 2):

Copy this code into your application controller. and your problem will solved.

```
Devise.mappings.each do |mapping, obj|
  define_method "current_#{mapping}_email" do
    eval("current_#{mapping}.email if current_#{mapping}")
end
helper_method "current_#{mapping}_email"
```

On view page/controller used according to your resource name
like if you have resource_name as user then its 'current_user_email'
or if have admin then 'current_admin_email'

Answer (score -1):

This works!

I added a custom method `current_user_email` as follows!

Add a file devise_ext.rb in config/initializers:

And in that file, add your custom methods in this way:

module Devise
      module Controllers
        # Those helpers are convenience methods added to ApplicationController.
        module Helpers

```
      def self.define_helpers(mapping) #:nodoc:
        mapping = mapping.name

        class_eval <<-METHODS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
          def authenticate_#{mapping}!(opts={})
            opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
            warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
          end

          def #{mapping}_signed_in?
            !!current_#{mapping}
          end

          def current_#{mapping}
            @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
          end

          def #{mapping}_session
            current_#{mapping} && warden.session(:#{mapping})
          end

          def current_#{mapping}_email
            @current_#{mapping}.email if @current_#{mapping}
          end
        METHODS

        ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
          helper_method "current_#{mapping}", "#{mapping}_signed_in?", "#{mapping}_session", "current_#{mapping}_email"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

P.S. I don't think this is the best way to do this. But it works. I tried this in one of my applications! You can use this code till I find a better way to do this :)

Comment: Yes that's what the devise does but the question is not how we create a dynamic method. It's how we can add our method with the methods of devise.

Comment: You can do that by overriding the devise classes.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this without overriding devise methods